# Laravel 5: access custom defined route info

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there away to return custom defined info in `route` definition, like return them for current route:

```
$request->route()->getAction();
```

Sample of route:

```
Route::GET('users/{me}/{uid}',['uses'=>'user@users', 'as'=>'users_me', 'sys_cache'=>false]);
```

Is there away to return `sys_cache` value using route name `users_me`?

Note: `users_me` isn't current requested route,

thanks,

Comment: Why you don't use this boolean variable in controller or middleware?

Comment: This process need to be handle in Middleware on all routes

Comment: Please give us more details. I can't understand your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but looks right going through the code:

```
$action = Route::getRoutes()->getByName('users_me')->getAction();
$sysCache = $action['sys_cache'];
```

`Route::getRoutes()` should get you the `RouteCollection`. `getByName()` should get you the route in the collection by the route name. `getAction()` should get you the action array defined on the route.